# JPEG Decoding problems with WIC

Tags: c++, windows, jpeg, wic

I am currently trying to load images from disk into memory using WIC. I used the MSDN documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-resources-textures-how-to) to write my code.

Everything works fine for loading PNG images. Loading JPEG images works without any error but does not produce the correct result! The interesting thing is, that when I convert the image from JPEG to PNG (using irfan view) the error persists.

Consider the following test image:

[image: Original image]

[image: Converted image from memory (inspected with Image Watch for Visual Studio)]

As you can see the image got shrunk in the x direction and all color information is gone. However, when you zoom in you can see that there is still some color present, but it doesn’t look like expected:

[image: Zoom in with Image Watch for visual studio]

(Problems persist when uploading the image as texture to the GPU)

I have striped out my WIC loading code omitting error handling and resource freeing for readability:

```cpp
// CoInitialize(NULL) called in main

// WIC Factory
IWICImagingFactory* ptrFactory = NULL;
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&ptrFactory));

// Open decoder
IWICBitmapDecoder* ptrDecoder = NULL;
ptrFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(fileName, NULL, GENERIC_READ, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand, &ptrDecoder)

// Get first frame
IWICBitmapFrameDecode* ptrFrameDecoder = NULL;
ptrDecoder->GetFrame(0, &ptrFrameDecoder));

// Read formate
WICPixelFormatGUID frameNativeFormat;
ptrFrameDecoder->GetPixelFormat(&frameNativeFormat);

// Computing target format selectConverterWic(...) and selectConverterDx(...) are just some very basic functions for selecting the right convert to formate by iterating over an std::array witch contains the mappings suggested by the MSDC article mentioned above
WICPixelFormatGUID targetFormat;
DXGI_FORMAT targetFormatDx;
if (!selectConverterDx(frameNativeFormat, &targetFormatDx)) {
    // Try to find WIC to WIC converter
    selectConverterWic(frameNativeFormat, &targetFormat)
    selectConverterDx(targetFormat, &targetFormatDx)
}else {
    memcpy(&targetFormat, &frameNativeFormat, sizeof(GUID));
}

// Get format info
IWICComponentInfo* ptrCmpInfo = NULL;
ptrFactory->CreateComponentInfo(targetFormat, &ptrCmpInfo);

// Get type
WICComponentType ptrCmpType;
ptrCmpInfo->GetComponentType(&ptrCmpType);


// Get info from type
IWICPixelFormatInfo* ptrFormatInfo = NULL;
ptrCmpInfo->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&ptrFormatInfo));

// Get BBP
UINT uiBitsPerPixel;
ptrFormatInfo->GetBitsPerPixel(&uiBitsPerPixel);

// ID3D12Device->CheckFeatureSupport(...) and fallback omitted

// Image size
UINT width, height;
ptrFrameDecoder->GetSize(&width, &height);

// Tempory memory allocation
UINT rowPitch = (width * uiBitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
SIZE_T imageSize = (SIZE_T)rowPitch * (SIZE_T)height;
void* workMemory = malloc(imageSize);

// Check if direct copy is possible
if (memcmp(&frameNativeFormat, &targetFormat, sizeof(GUID)) == 0){
    ptrFrameDecoder->CopyPixels(NULL, rowPitch, (UINT)imageSize, (BYTE*)workMemory);
}else{
    // Format conversion (Got never hit by a jpeg file; I tried to force it but results weren't right asswell)
    IWICFormatConverter* ptrFormatConverter = NULL;
    ptrFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&ptrFormatConverter);
    ptrFormatConverter->Initialize(ptrFrameDecoder, targetFormat, WICBitmapDitherTypeErrorDiffusion, NULL, 0, WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom);
    ptrFormatConverter->CopyPixels(NULL, rowPitch, (UINT)imageSize, (BYTE*)workMemory);
    
}

// I inspected workMemory and got the result you saw above
// Some more code for copying data to user supplied parameters
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It looks like a file format problem. How about to check every HRESULT return from every method call? There are maybe some error results.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I did checked every single method call witch returned something with if(FAILED(hr = CALL(...)){... return hr;} and got no error. Is there any special error code I need to explicitly check?

Comment: I have traced down the value of my HRESULT hr and it never takes another value than S_OK.

Comment: Are you sure about your pitch/stride computation? Or post a small reproducing project.

Comment: Well I don't know. Maybe there is somthing wrong with this line. But it worked with PNG's and it is the same on the MSDN sample. BBP * width / 8 makes sense for me because it coresponds to the width in bytes (stride) of a scanline. I have no idea why they used the +7... but removing it is still producing the same output. The stride is also correct I vertified it (at least for my interpretation). Maybe the +7 is to ensure that with round off the calaculation will still result in the appropriate stride. I will start from scratch now a create an only image loading example.I will post it here soon

Comment: looks like classic pitch/stride problem (most likely in your code of course)

Comment: Stupid mistake on my side here! In my code to check the target DXGI_FORMATE compatibility I forgot an inversion. So i always ran into the fallback code which resulted in no conversion. Looks like this was fine for PNGs but failed for JPEGs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above is totally fine and works! The problem was in the omitted DirectX 12 Feature support check:

```
ID3D12Device->CheckFeatureSupport(...)
```

I forgot an inversion which resulted that the following code snipped was executed

```
memcpy(&frameNativeFormat, &GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGBA, sizeof(GUID));
targetFormatDx = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
uiBitsPerPixel = 32;
```

The second bug was that I override "frameNativeFormat" instead of "targetFormat" which resulted that no conversion was executed (At least for JPEGs).

Fixing both issues gave me a decent texture loading algorithm (At least for Windows)